# Can a capacitor prevent over-amperage of lithium ion batteries?

Tags: batteries, capacitor, electricity, electrical

I have an electric motorcycle I've built, I have 7 Nissan Leaf battery packs in series to make 48v nominal. Unfortunately, after a month of enjoying the acceleration a bit too much, the batteries no longer hold charge for more than 15 minutes.

Some research shows that the max amperage is around 240 amps, could a capacitor, or several capacitors be used to provide 360-400 amps over a short period of time (a few seconds) and keep the batteries from being damaged, or is my best route (which will be costly and VERY difficult) to figure out where to stuff double the amount of batteries and run a series of paralleled pairs?

Comment: Short the battery terminals. Now what will the capacitor do to help?

Comment: You can get an idea of how big the capacitor you may need using E=(CV^2)/2. Good luck.

Comment: Well, there are apparently supercaps out there, but to use them you may need a non-trivial charging and discharging circuit.

Comment: @A.K. That was my understanding as well

Answer (score 1):

NO.

Batteries are simply capacitors with more toxic electrode/electrolyte combination which results in perhaps > 1k ~ 10k x more capacitance with a galvanic cell voltage but caps can withstand 10k times life charge cycles with lower ESR*C=T charge time {figure of merit} and less aggressive ageing on the materials.

But you can trickle charge the packs then dismantle them and locate the bad cells that are mismatched more than a few % in cell voltage by matching them in strings... If you search Youtube and find out how.  Pulse load tests are better and Ah tests are the best for matching.

Excessive current accelerates the imbalance in charge capacity and it only takes 1  bad apple to make a string fail.

Comment: Umm, no. Batteries are not simply capacitors. Batteries store energy in a chemical reaction and capacitors store it by building up charge on two conductors separated by an insulator. They work on very different principles.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is very incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capacitor bank to provide momentary high current. You'll want parallel voltage regulators for generating the 48V nominal. The capacitor side would also need boost regulation so you can use the full range of energy stored. Finally be sure you have an appropriate capacitor bank charger that only uses what's left over from your 240 amp budget.

Comment: I think his question is if it is possible to make a circuit that would provide a short burst of current from a battery of capacitors while keeping peak current through the main battery low. The capacitor would recharge from the main battery between the periods of peak usage.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I said nothing about charging. I have a BMS in place; an Orion BMS, and I have a current controller, I want MORE amperage than my batteries are recommended to allow, nearly double. The amperage needed to propel the bike decreases as the speed of the bike increases (other factors counteract this, such as wind resistance, rider weight, incline/decline, etc). My thought was, a large enough capacitor would discharge FIRST, and the batteries would have to make up the remaining amperage, limiting the potential for damage to the batteries. Am I wrong?

Comment: Also, BMS' do not provide current to an electric motor. BMS's do nothing outside of controlling charge and SOC for any number of lithium ion cells individually, instead of charging in a series array like you could with lead acid. I think you're largely confused about how electric vehicles operate, do not understand simple electrical design or you misunderstood the question.

Comment: Yes, but you need to get some charge in the capacitor first. If you attach a large enough empty supercap to your battery, it will draw more current than the motor.

Comment: E.g. https://www.maxwell.com/images/documents/K2Series_DS_1015370_5_20141104.pdf. >3000A short circuit current.

Comment: Hi @Matth3w, thanks for some clarification in your question. Are there two questions here then? 1. How to generate a temporary high current bank and 2. Why your batteries don't hold charge anymore? Let me know so I can amend an answer. I would appreciate if you amend your question as well. We seem to both devalue each other's knowledge because of a misunderstanding in question and answer.

Comment: No, neither of those are my question. The batteries were overamped; thats what i'm trying to prevent NEXT TIME with the capacitor. Batteries are replaced, I'm just curious if i'd need a "regular" cap, or a series of them, what size, or if i'd need to go to super caps.

Comment: @Matth3w: what is the capacity of your battery in W h?

Comment: @Matth3w we can't specify anything without more specifics. Can you provide a schematic of your circuit? Existing part numbers and datasheets? What are your product priorities? (minimize cost? minimize space? efficeincy?) A.K has already provided you with an energy equation for a rough estimate.

Comment: A.K.; the capacitor would take up more space than I have available, I opted instead to double my battery count and parallel sets instead. Thank you for your help! Wish I could have awarded you, respost as an answer and get some credit!